# I keep getting this "Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target...." error. How do I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio

I attached a screenshot of the warning I get.

I tried the solutions I found on stackoverflow and other websites but they didnt work.

My instructor said it happens if you are typing to open a zipped file or a file moved or when a project is split up.

Not sure what that exactly means I should do. Can you help explain that to me? Or if you have a solution to it?

Please and thanks.